# missing returned data from sails.js file upload

Tags: javascript, sails.js

I have written a simple function to handle upload of files in my sails.js app.

```
let upload = file.upload((err, uploadedFiles) => {
  if (err) {
    return res.serverError(err);
  } else {
    return res.send({ data: uploadedFiles });
  }
});
```

When the upload is complete I am redirected to a page displaying raw json, which contains the uploaded file information (including the path).

[raw json response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtjfd.jpg)

What I am expecting when I `console.log(upload)` is the same information, however I am getting the writestream instead.

[console.log output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkMPP.jpg)

This is a problem for me because I would like to be able to extract the file name from the object and use it in another part of my program, but I can't do this because all I am able to access is the writestream.

I have tried using async/await and callbacks and can't seem to fix my issue.

Hopefully someone can help me!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A helpful person on the sails Gitter suggested that I use this package, which supports async/await: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-hook-uploads

I tested it out with the following code and it works:

```
let upload = await sails
  .uploadOne(file, {
    maxBytes: 3000000,
  })
  .intercept('E_EXCEEDS_UPLOAD_LIMIT', 'tooBig')
  .intercept(
    (err) => new Error('The photo upload failed: ' + util.inspect(err))
  );
```